# Problem with using spacy to lemmatize text and transform into CSV

Tags: python, csv, anaconda, spacy

I’m using Anaconda and I want to lemmatize, tokenize and morphologically annotate a text using spacy. I have a text file which I want to transform into a CSV file with all annotations etc. using the following script:

```
import os
import re
import csv
import glob
from collections import Counter
nlp = spacy.load("de_core_news_md")
plaintextfolder = "" #here would be my file path
taggedfolder = "" #here would be my file path
language = "de"
doc = nlp("Dies ist ein Satz.")
for token in doc:
    print(token.text,token.pos_,token.lemma_,token.morph)

nlp = spacy.load("de_core_news_md")

def read_plaintext(file):
    with open(file, "r", encoding="utf-8") as infile:
        text = infile.read()
        text = re.sub("’", "'", text)
        return text 
        
def save_tagged(taggedfolder, filename, tagged):
    taggedfilename = taggedfolder + "/" + filename + ".csv"
    with open(taggedfilename, "w", encoding="utf-8") as outfile:
        writer = csv.writer(outfile, delimiter='\t')
        for token in tagged:
            token = token.text,token.pos_,token.lemma_,token.morph
            writer.writerow(token)      
            
def main(plaintextfolder, taggedfolder, language):
    print("\n--preprocess")
    if not os.path.exists(taggedfolder):
        os.makedirs(taggedfolder)
    counter = 0
    for file in glob.glob(plaintextfolder + "*.txt"):
        filename, ext = os.path.basename(file).split(".")
        counter +=1
        print("next: file", counter, ":", filename)
        text = read_plaintext(file)
        tagged = nlp(text)
        save_tagged(taggedfolder, filename, tagged)

main(plaintextfolder, taggedfolder, language)
```

What I would like to have at the end is a CSV file looking like this:

```
Dies PRON Dies Case=Nom|Gender=Neut|Number=Sing|PronType=Dem
ist AUX sein Mood=Ind|Number=Sing|Person=3|Tense=Pres|VerbForm=Fin
ein DET einen Case=Nom|Definite=Ind|Gender=Masc|Number=Sing|PronType=Art
Satz NOUN Satz Case=Nom|Gender=Masc|Number=Sing
```

But I only get a weird CSV file looking like this (I copied only the first lines):

```
"'  PUNCT   '   "

"D'i'e's    X   D'i'e's Foreign=Yes"

"'  PUNCT   '   "

"'  PUNCT   '   "

"i's't  X   i's't   Foreign=Yes"

"'  PUNCT   '   "
```

If you could help me with this issue, I would really appreciate it!

Comment: Hi, can you give the origital line from the input file, please.

Answer (score 0):

So as a general note, when asking on StackOverflow you should reduce your problem to the smallest part, and there's too much going on in your code sample. That said...

I cannot reproduce your problem exactly, but I can get part of it. I was able to get some weird lines kind of similar to your if I didn't call `.strip()` on the text. So you need to make sure that you don't pass newlines to the CSV writer - it's not escaping them correctly. For example, if my input file contains "Das ist gut", the output looks like this:

```
Das PRON    der Case=Nom|Gender=Neut|Number=Sing|PronType=Dem
ist AUX sein    Mood=Ind|Number=Sing|Person=3|Tense=Pres|VerbForm=Fin
gut ADV gut Degree=Pos
"
"   SPACE   "
"   Case=Nom|Gender=Masc|Number=Sing
```

This looks wrong, but what happens is the fourth line just includes a `\n` inside quotes. The fifth line has the closing quote and then an opening quote for another quoted newline.

You may be able to fiddle with the newline settings in the csvwriter to fix it but it's probably easier to just strip newlines.

For your tokens like `D'i'e's`, that looks like either your input text was bad or something went wrong with your regex for quotes, though in the current form it looks OK.

Anyway, to understand what's going wrong, I suggest you debug your code step by step to understand what text you're reading in and what the input to the csvwriter is.